# Problem trying to relocate WC to new repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have several working copies that were checked out of old repositories.
The old repositories are now combined into a new repository, therefore the repository name and the locations inside the new repository have changed.
Now I want to relocate these working copies to their new locations into the new repository.

When doing a Relocate with TortoiseSVN, I get a warning:

> It seems you are trying to **relocate** your working copy to a different path inside the same repository.
>   From: https://old-repository/oldpath/folder
>   To: https://new-repository/newpath/folder
>   A relocate is only needed if the path **to** a repository has changed.
>   Changing to a different path **inside** a repository is done by a switch operation.

But it's not a different path inside the same repository. It really is a newly created repository with a different path / name.
When I ingore the warning and continue with the Relocate, I get an error:

> The repository at 'https://new-repository/newpath/folder' has uuid 
>   'd3b83275-bf16-aa42-9467-f8a402003233', but the WC has '30e22be1-af51-d84d-ad8f-d4e8545a4735'

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What's wrong with simply making a patch of your working copy changes, checking out the new repository and then applying the patch?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this, I'm just trying to understand why the Relocate doesn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can not do **relocate** to a new repository, you need to delete your working copy and do a clean checkout. **Relocate** can only be used if a repository has been moved unchanged to a new server or the server has got a new name.

Answer (score 8):

If you really wanted to force what you're attempting to do, you could use the command:
[svnadmin setuuid](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.setuuid.html)

to set the new repoistory to the same GUID as the old.

That would take care of the uuid error, and enable you to try again the `svn switch`.
  (with or without the `--relocate`; I can't tell from your descriiption exactly how you've rearranged the paths inside the repository)